# Não consigo atribuir retorno da expressão na variável do SSIS

Tags: visual-studio-2015, ssis, business-intelligence

[Task para inserir Valor na Variável pelo resultado do select](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ir5EA.png)

[image: Task para fazer o update no campo valor usando como values o valor da variável]

[image: Select que insere os valores na variável update]
[image: Update na tabela STG_Vendas usando o valor da variável][image: Propriedades da variável]

O meu intuito com essa lógica é passar uma coluna calculada de um arquivo excel para outro usando uma área de stage onde só quero modificar uma coluna na tabela do banco para depois inserir dentro do arquivo excel.
Por isso estou usando variável para pegar o resultado do select e usar como valor no update, pois existe mais de uma conexão.
Porém o valor da variável não muda quando executo a task[image: Conjunto de valores da task][image: Parametros da task]

Answer (score 0):

A variável que está a utilizar no mapeamento não é a mesma que está a sair do Conjunto de Resultados. Já agora, quando utiliza uma variável que está mapeada, não precisa de colocar o nome dela, basta meter na query um ponto de interrogação (?) que ele vai utilizar as variáveis mapeadas com base no nome do mapeamento delas (0,1,2,3).

Comment: Poderia me dar um exemplo de query ?

Comment: Na sua query do Update:

Update STG_Vendas
Set Vlr_Compra = ?
Where Codigo_Produto is not null